# How to append to an array that is a value in a Swift dictionary

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

Let's assume I have a dictionary that accepts a string as the key and an array as value:

```
var d = [String: [Int]]()
d["k"] = [Int]()
```

Now I would like to `append()` to the array that is under the `["k"]`. How do I do that?

```
[Int](d["k"]).append(1) // error
(d["k"] as [Int]).append(1) // error
```

I guess this is something really basic but I cannot figure it out... thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because Dictionary and Array are both struct types, you can't modify the Array in place, but instead have to extract and restore it:

```
if var items = d["k"] {
    items.append(1)
    d["k"] = items
}
else {
    d["k"] = [1]
}
```

Comment: Actually, 'edit', this doesn't work either... It does... it should be "items!" or "items?" Thanks so much!

Comment: yeah, d["k"] is an optional, so you have to handle the unwrapping.

Comment: Antonio gives a better answer below in the case that you know the key already exists.

Answer (score 3):

If the element for that key exists, you can simply do:

```
d["k"]?.append(1)
```

Note that if no element exists for the `"k"` key, then nothing happens. If you want to ensure there's actually an array for that key, just add this before appending:

```
if d["k"] == nil {
    d["k"] = []
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
var d = [String: [Int]]()
d["k"] = [Int]()
if var items = d["k"] {
    items.append(1)
    d["k"] = items
}
```

You have to:

1. pull it out
2. unwrap the Optional
3. assign it to a `var` reference
4. append, and
5. put it back again

The `if var` line does the first three steps all in one.

Answer (score -1):

All other answers are correct, but If you feel annoying to check `nil`, unwrap ...

I made a custom operator.

With this, you can *unconditionally* expand `Optional` arrays

```
infix operator +=! {
    associativity right
    precedence 90
    assignment
}

func +=!<T, S:SequenceType where S.Generator.Element == T>(inout lhs:[T]?, rhs:S) {
    if lhs == nil {
        // the target is `nil`, create a new array
        lhs = Array(rhs)
    }
    else {
        // the target is not `nil`, just expand it
        lhs! += rhs
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var d = [String: [Int]]()

// ... d["test"] may or may not exists ...

d["test"] +=! [1]
```