# How to specify that a Dictionary.Value must be an array

Tags: swift, generics

After seeing the question "How do I append an item to a an array in a dictionary?" for the nth time, I decided to write an extension to simplify the whole thing.

I started with a global function, but it has the obvious problems that it's not scoped, and requires that the dictionary be passed by reference explicitly:

```
func appendValue<K, V>(value:V, forKey key:K, inout inDict dictionary:[K:[V]]) {
    if var items = dictionary[key] {
        items.append(value)
        dictionary[key] = items
    }
    else {
        dictionary[key] = [value]
    }
}

var d = [String:[Int]]()
appendValue(1, forKey: "k", inDict: &d)
```

It works, but it's kind of clunky.  I'd much rather be able to simply use `d.appendValue(1, forKey:"k")` so I tried to put it in an extension on Dictionary:

```
extension Dictionary {
    mutating func appendValue<V where Value == [V]>(value:V, forKey key:Key) {
        if var items = self[key] {
            items.append(value)
            self[key] = items
        }
        else {
            self[key] = [value]
        }
    }
}
```

Now the where clause seems to compile ok, but it's not having the expected effect.  I was hoping that it would require that Dictionary.Value be some Array type, but I get errors on the items.append and assignment statements that indicate that that's not the case, and in fact, the chunk:

```
var d2 = [String:Int]()
d2.appendValue(1, forKey: "k")
```

doesn't generate the expected error that `d2.Value` isn't an Array.

Thinking that the problem might also be using short-hand notations, I tried changing `[V]` to `Array<V>` but that didn't seem to help, although it does give an error on the where clause that `same-type requirement makes generic parameter 'Value' non-generic`

So the question is, can I write an extension method on `Dictionary` that requires that `Dictionary.Value` be an Array-type, and if so, how?

Comment: Note that `self[key]?.append(value)` works - less known feature of dictionaries and optionals :) So you just need to create the empty array if not existing - read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28376624/148357)

Comment: `var d2 = [String:Int]()` should be `var d2 = [String:[Int]]()` right?

Comment: Oooh, good point, but doesn't actually solve the question :)

Comment: The duplicate question is about arrays, but the same concept applies to dictionaries

Comment: No Jawwad, that's the point, I want to require that d2.ValueType be an Array, and generate an error on the code I give.

Comment: Eh not exactly a duplicate @antonio, but close enough and pretty much what I was afraid of.

Comment: @David well, the point is that you cannot add an extension method which adds a constraint to the generic type - I guess the only way is via a global function. But if you think I made a mistake by closing let me know... :)

Comment: Nah, closing it is fine.  Just a comment that leaving it and not deleting it is a good idea for the added context and reference point.  I do have a procedural question though, how did it close without a vote?

Comment: @David If you don't like "clunky" `inout` syntax, custom operator is an option. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28377579/3804019

Comment: @David: Regarding your "procedural question": Gold badge holders in a category can close questions as a duplicate immediately, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230865/increase-close-vote-weight-for-gold-tag-badge-holders/231212#231212. It's called "Dupe hammer" or "Mighty Mjölnir".